# jquery dialog field only works before user Input

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

Before I start describing my Problem: Thank you for taking the time to read this!

I am trying to code an basic Event-Calendar. The user should be able to create events and update event-parameters. If an existing event is clicked, a jquery Dialog is ment to open and show an editable textfield for each event-parameter. Now so far this works fine. The only problem is that, as soon as any of the parameters is manualy changed and saved, the Textfields do not accept any further modification of there Value. Those should normaly be set to the parameter-value of the clicked event before the dialog opens.

I already tried to find an answer to my problem via stackoverflows serch function and google. I tried a lot of the things i found like using the dialog create parameter and setting it to a function that would assign the event parameters to the input fields or to create the form code dynamicaly each time just before the dialog opens. Nothing seems to help.

I guess I am missing an essential point to my Problem.

I am using the "fullcalendar" JQuery-Plugin and codesnippets of the jquery-ui dialog-form template.
(fullcalendar: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ )
(jquery dialog-form: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form )

Thank you very much for the time and effort you already took to read this.

Here are parts of my Code:

```
    ---Initialisation of fullcalendar----

eventClick: function (event, element) {

     var id = $( "#id" ),
     title = $( "#title" ),
     allFields = $( [] ).add( id ).add( title );

    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog
        ({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 320,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        close: function() 
                {
                allFields.attr( "value", "" );
                },
        buttons: {
        "Update Event": function() 
                    {
                        var bValid = true;
                    // To-Do: Entry Check Logic
                        if ( bValid ) 
                            {
                                event.title=$("#title").val();

                                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);
                                $( this ).dialog( "close" );

                            }
                    },
        Cancel: function() 
                    {
                        $(this).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                }       
            });     

        $("#id").attr("value",event._id);
        $("#title").attr("value",event.title);
        $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );

        }
        });
    });

----Some Css----

</head>
<body >
<div id='calendar'></div>

<div class="lightness" id="dialog-form" title="Parameter">
<p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>
<form>
<fieldset id="beforeSubmit">
<label for="id">Id</label>
<input type="text" name="id" id="id"  />
<label for="title">Title</label>
<input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="" />

</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well after quite a while of agony and "banging-my-head-through-the-Wall" i found a solution.
As it seems

> .attr("vaule",something)

is not the method of Choice here. It works fine to define the value befor any kind of User Input but fails to update the value thereafter.
What i should have used is:

> .val(something)

Now as to why this method may write after user Input, while .attr may not:
I simply have no Idea.

Thanks to everyone that has read my Question!
I hope someone here might be able to explain why this happens.